# CORS issues with DEManager Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, cors

Is there any possibility to use DEManager without facing CORS issues? Something like whitelisting the domains for our external websites?

Answer (score 0):

You can just update the form action URL to start with `https`:

`https://cl.exct.net/DEManager.aspx`

You can also use the base SFMCs URLs with `https` in other places to work around CORS -- like landing pages:

`https://pages.exacttarget.com/page.aspx?QS=11111111`

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your response.
We have the https: in our HTML, which is placed on the website of our client so we can't change the url to pages.exacttarget. Is there another solution u know of?

Comment: You can purchase an SSL cert through SFMC and have them apply it to the domain in question.